# Rename the "slices" in Pie chart using Highcharts in shiny R

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

Used the below code to  make a pie chart in shiny R interface using Highcharts but was unable to name the slices. I have used a dataset stored in csv format from my app folder.

```
  output$Hist<-renderHighchart({

        data<-read.csv(paste0(getwd(),"/data.csv"),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        highchart() %>%
          hc_chart(type = "pie") %>% 
          hc_plotOptions(
            series = list(showInLegend = TRUE)
          ) %>% 
          hc_add_series(data =  data$Count, name = data$X) %>%
    hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 0,
                     pointFormat = "Count: {point.y}") %>%
 hc_legend(enabled = TRUE)%>%
```

Image of the chart:
[image: this is the chart output]

[image: sample data]

Comment: please provide sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
library(highcharter)
data <- data.frame(X=c("name1","name2"),Count =c(20,30))
highchart() %>%
hc_add_series_labels_values(data$X, data$Count, name = "Pie",colorByPoint = TRUE, type = "pie")
```

[image]